# Is this correct design approach for splitting logic between activity and other class

Tags: android

I have an android/programming design question. For some reason I feel my design is awkward but if it is correct (no issues) then  I would like a confirmation so I know I am on the right path.

Often I come across where I have Activity (lets say it has map). I don't want to put everything in this class ( ie map  work). I usually create the activity class and another class (say map worker). I pass the activity as a reference to the map worker class, so that map worker class can method in there. Something like that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(){

        MapWorker myWorker = new MapWorker(this);
    }

    public renderUpdate  (Marker m){

        mapView.addMarker(m)
    } 
}
```

The map worker class is as follows

```
public class MapWorker {

    MainActivity act;

    public void MapWorker(MainActivity act){

        this.act = act;
    }

    public doWork(){

        //do lots of work
        .
        .
        .
        act.renderUpdate(marker)
    }
}
```

These classes have two way linking as you see. Is this ok or should I do it differently?and Why?

Thank you so much

Comment: There is no need to keep such separation. You can separate the logic and the data holder class but what is the point to pass activity reference to another class and do your stuff there. You can use this approach if the logic is repetitive in different classes and you want to reuse it.

Comment: The reason is because I have a lot of other different logics in addition to the maplogic and it will end up huge class (harder to maintain) .. So I wanted to break the functionality by class